# How can I hide "Open Qs" notification in Quora?

Tags: quora

How can I hide "Open Qs" notification in Quora?

[image]

Comment: You may want to hide it with the element picker in any adblocker. However, about that... [Element picker can't hide Quora's header. How to fix?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103198/63572)